# Convert DateTime to string "yyyy-mm-dd"

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, console-application, converters

Im wondering how to convert a DateTime to a string value (yyyy-mm-dd). I have a console application and i want the user to be able to write a Date as "yyyy-mm-dd" which are then converted as a string.

I have tried this but it works in oposite direction it seem. The idea is that the user enters a Start date and an End date with Console.ReadLine. Then these values are stored as strings in string A and B wich could then be used later. Is that possible?

```
string A = string.Empty;
string B = string.Empty;
DateTime Start = DateTime.ParseExact(A, "yyyy-mm-dd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine("Enter StartDate! (yyyy-mm-dd)");
Start = Console.ReadLine();      
DateTime End = DateTime.ParseExact(A, "yyyy-mm-dd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine("Enter EndDate! (yyyy-mm-dd)");
End = Console.ReadLine();
```

Thank you

Comment: Use `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");` to convert datetime to string.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're on the right track but you're a little off. For example try something like this when reading in:

```
var s = Console.ReadLine();
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(s,"yyyy-MM-dd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You might want to use `DateTime.TryParseExact()` as well, it's a bit safer and you can handle what happens when someone types garbage in. As it stands you'll get a nice exception currently.

When outputting to a specific format you can use the same format with `DateTime.ToString()`, for example:

```
var date_string = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful, works great. I tried this before wich did the same thing but used strings instead of DateTime for input:       Console.WriteLine("Enter StartDate! (yyyy-mm-dd)");
        string A = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter EndDate! (yyyy-mm-dd)");
        string B = Console.ReadLine();

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear do you want transform `DateTime` to `String` or vice versa.

From `DateTime` to `String`: just *format* the source:

```
 DateTime source = ...;
 String result = source.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

From `String` to `DateTime`: *parse* the source *exact*:

```
 String source = ...;
 DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(source, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or TryParseExact (if you want to *check user's input*)

```
 String source = ...;
 DateTime result;

 if (DateTime.TryParseExact(source, "yyyy-MM-dd", 
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                            out result) {
   // parsed
 }
 else {
   // not parsed (incorrect format)
 }
```

Comment: `mm` shouldbe Capital `MM`

Answer (score 0):

For converting a DateTime to a string value in required (yyyy-mm-dd) format, we can do this way:

```
DateTime testDate = DateTime.Now; //Here is your date field value.
string strdate = testDate.ToString("yyyy, MMMM dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can format a DateTime value with ToString(), you cannot directly format a nullable DateTime (DateTime?).  First, you have to convert it.  ((DateTime)someDate).ToString().  However, you will need to handle the case if the variable is null as this will throw an exception otherwise.
DateTime? dateTime = null;

```
if (dateTime != null)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(((DateTime)dateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
}
else
{
    // Handle null date value
    dateTime = DateTime.Now;
    Debug.WriteLine(((DateTime)dateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
}
```